# How to update the contents of a ComboBox in a HTML file using the contents of another with JQuery and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I am a beginner to JQuery and Ajax and wanted to know how i can update the contents of a combobox in a html file when the content of another combobox changes .

I have two select boxes and want the second one to get updated as the user selects an option in the first one . This question has been asked before but the solutions weren't clear enough.

```
$.ajax({

            type : "POST",
            data : {
                brand : document.form1.brandsFrom.value
            },
            url : "BrandsController/ajaxquery",
            beforeSend : function() {
            },
            async : false,
            success : function(data) {
                result = data;
            }
        });
```

I am calling this ajax code in the function that executes with onchange listener of the first SELECT tab .
Whats the best approach to go for it . Like I have a function in one of my classes that can do the processing part but how do i call it through the url parameter of this AJAX code .

Comment: what are you running on your backend? php? the url you call should lead to a script, that reads the post value, retrieves the desired data from your database or whatever and returns that value as a json. when the data has been sent back from your server, your success function will be called (its a callback function) and will be able to handle the data however you want (e.g. manipulate your second combobox).

Comment: No i don't have a php file . I only have a java class with a function that i want to run and through that i was hoping to populate the other select menu like i did the first one . This is only an idea and i don't know if its the best way to do it . Any suggestion would be great

Comment: so I assume you dont run java as an applet on your webpage, as it doesn't make sense to me, that you would use javascript (here: jquery) in this case. when you're running java only at your backend (and you use java's servlet classes - I'm no expert in java), it's the same... return a json with the data and your jquery ajax-function will catch that data and handle it e.g. like this: success:function(data){console.log(data);} > outputs the data in your browser console

Comment: Thanks . I will try it . I guess i will first need to learn how to retrieve data from database in php though.

Comment: you're welcome. if you use java, why don't you stick to java? it doesnt matter what you're running on your server. php is probably the easiest one to learn, but it's up to you, if you run java, php, ruby, node.js or whatever. just to be sure: java (backend) is not javascript (frontend) - both are completely different languages and mainly just share the 'java' in their name. ... it's not so clear, what your actual point of knowledge is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$( "#comboBox1" ).change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        data : {
            brand : document.form1.brandsFrom.value
        },
        url : "BrandsController/ajaxquery",
        beforeSend : function() {
        },
        async : false,
        success : function(data) {
            newOptions = data;
            changeSelectOptions("#comboBox2",newOptions);
        }
    });
});
```

The "BrandsController/ajaxquery" url should return something like this:

```
{
    "Option 1": "value1",
    "Option 2": "value2",
    "Option 3": "value3"
};
```

Just write this function that change select options

```
function changeSelectOptions(selectId,newOptions) {
    var $element = $(selectId);
    $element.empty(); // remove old options
    $.each(newOptions, function(value,key) {
      $element.append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value", value).text(key));
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks . I think this will work .  can you also tell me how to map url "BrandsController/ajazquery" to one of the functions in BrandsController class that will return that Object thats required . That mapping part is what i was most confused about as most of the solution to similar question mapped to a php file rather than a java class function that i want to do here

Comment: why not search for 'java ajax example'? seems like the links given there should help you or let you concretize your questions.